# The tags below posts on search results occupies the same space as the page number navigation links on narrow screens

Tags: bug, search, responsive-design, pagination

This bug appears when the view gets sufficiently narrow (the first four pages, and the last four pages are less affected). This seems to have started happening in the last week or so.

The links to change page cannot be used, and I have to edit the URL manually (not ideal) to change page - even the "Prev" and "Next" links don't work (possibly for Z order reasons).

- This affects Chrome and Edge (89.0.4389.90 and 89.0.774.50) on Windows 10, Chrome 89.0.4389.86 on Android 11 - but not Firefox 86.0 on Windows 10.
- All Stack Exchange sites seem affected.
- The specific search query doesn't affect the behaviour other than to change the exact number of pixels that the bad behaviour starts happening at.

Could this please be fixed? Manually editing URLs is very cumbersome.

---

For example, [a search for `a` on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=a)

Page 1 - the transition is at 315px:

> [image]

Page 2 - the transition is at 364px:

> [image]

Page 3 - the transition is at 364px:

> [image]

Page 4 - the transition is at 364px:

> [image]

Page 5 - the transition is at 428px:

> [image]

Page 15 - the transition is at 646px:

> [image]

Page 29 - the transition is at 646px:

> [image]

Page 30 - the transition is at 393px:

> [image]

Page 33 - the transition is at 344px:

> [image]

Comment: What is the width of your screen in these examples? I believe there is a minimum width that is supported.

Comment: I had to make the pages pretty narrow to reproduce on my computer, some of the screenshots were taken at >600px wide. Here is a screenshot from my phone (the screen is 1080px wide - I've not applied any additional scaling to the page), where I first noticed the bug: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWSJY.png

Comment: Confirmed: this doesn’t happen on Firefox Nightly 88.0a1 desktop (any width) or Firefox for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed - I can't reproduce it on Chrome 108.0.5359.99 or Firefox 108.0 on Windows 11, or Chrome 108.0.5359.79 on Android 13.

A screenshot from Chrome:

[image: The tags and the navigation links are now clearly separated]